# What additional settings are needed to change Angular default port from 4200 to other numbers?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I am learning asp.net core webapi  and angular 13 using Visual Studio Community 2022.

The solution consists of two projects with the following templates:

- `Standalone TypeScript Angular Project`
- `Asp.Net Core Web API`

I did the following modifications:

- Changing the port target in `src\proxy.conf.js` of the Angular project from a random number to `40443` as follows:

  ```
  const PROXY_CONFIG = [
     {
       // other settings are trimmed for the sake of simplicity
       target: "https://localhost:40443",
     }
  ]
  ```
- Changing the https port in `properties\launchSettings.json` of the Web API project from a random number to `40443` as follows:

  ```
   {
     // other settings are truncated for the sake of simplicity
     "profiles": {
       "BackendProjectName": {
         "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:40443;http://localhost:5042"
       }
      }
     }
   }
  ```

  Note: the http port is kept with its default random value because I am not interested in the unsafe one right now.
- Reordering multiple startup projects as follows:
  [image]

When I pressed the `Start` button (in debug mode) and accepted the asp.net development certificate, two browsers were opened. They displayed correct results (weather forecast simulation data). Swagger is opened at port 40443 and the angular is opened at port 4200.

### Attempt to change Angular port from 4200 to 5000

As I want  the Angular to listen at port `5000` (for example), I added `"port": 5000` to `angular.json` as follows

```
"serve": {
  // other settings are truncated for the sake of simplicity
  "options": {
    "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.js",
    "port": 5000
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I got the following error displayed on the console window of the angular development server:

> [webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:5000/weatherforecast to https://localhost:40443/ [ECONNREFUSED] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

### Question

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also need to modify `launch.json` in the Angular project as follows.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "localhost (Chrome)",
      "url": "https://localhost:5000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
      "type": "edge",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "localhost (Edge)",
      "url": "https://localhost:5000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

It is a bit counter-intuitive because I created the projects with VS Community but `launch.json` is in `.vscode` that is hidden by VS Community.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to have angular listen to port 5000. The setting you mention is for the proxy (out of Angular to apis). The command you're looking for (to server you angular from a different port is:

```
ng serve --port 5000
```

Now its on localhost:5000.

Comment: Updated the answer, however you also have to change the last proxy setting back to what it was I think.

Comment: Hmmm, let's dig deeper.

Comment: See my answer. Thank you for your participation. :-)